# Graphical folding editor for JSON?

Tags: software-recommendation, editor, json

The Ubuntu repositories come with the package `xmlcopyeditor`, which installs [XML Copy Editor](https://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.io/index.php?page=ubuntu); a nice, graphical folding editor for the somewhat outdated [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) data file format.

[image: XML Copy Editor in Ubuntu]

I am looking for a similar graphical **folding** editor, but then for the increasingly popular [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data file format. That would be of tremendous help with inspecting large JSON files.

For all clarity: I am not looking for some JSON extension to a big box general text editor.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but any proper text editor can do folding (e.g. `geany` or  `codium`) for a ton of formats.